# Share Via crashes when mutly selection

Tags: android, android-gallery, multi-select, imageurl

My app can be lounched by Gallery's "sheare via" option.
when running on Galaxy S2 4.03 and more then one image being selected the application crashes when trying to get image url -

```
uri = (Uri) bundle.get("android.intent.extra.STREAM");
```

how it can be solved?
Thanks,
Eyal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html, you probably need to parse it this way:

```
ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```